# Git project submodule organizing

Tags: git, git-submodules, project-management

I have a git project which includes submodules. It looks something like this:
Project A
---- Project B (submodule)
---- Project C (submodule)
Project C uses code from both Projects A and B.
Project B uses code from Project C.
The problem that arises from this accursed situation is that when I want to make a pull request that contains changes that affects all the three projects, it becomes a mess to handle.
I wanted to know what is the best way to fix the current problem?
I thought about merging all of the projects into one but wanted to know if there is a better solution.
Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "uses code" ?

Comment: You could try to use the repo tool: https://source.android.com/setup/develop/repo

Comment: Thanks for the replies. I will check out the repo tool. But what i mean by "uses code" is that a function from one project calls the function from the other @Pratham .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Circular dependancies in projects is generally an opportunity to create problems and I recommend avoiding it. The exact solution is going to depend somewhat on your environment and requirements for the different projects. The main question to ask yourself is:

**Is there a clean interface between the projects, or, can there be?**

If we consider a micro service architecture then it makes sense to have a project per component with a strong interface between the components. This means that the team on project A has a 'contract' with the team on project B.

Without a clean interface then I would recommend compressing into a single repository. The main reason here is to make it easy for the developers. Typically changes will be required in sync between the two projects. Much easier to do in a single project than across multiple projects.

A couple more clues, do you always release the projects together, or can individual projects be released on their own? If you always release the projects together, then I would suggest compressing into a single project.

If you have any follow up questions, or, more information about the projects you would like me to consider, please leave a comment.

Comment: Thanks a lot James for the answer! Ive decided to compress into  a single project. 
I found this as a guide to do as you suggested: https://medium.com/altcampus/how-to-merge-two-or-multiple-git-repositories-into-one-9f8a5209913f
Do you have any better recommendations?
Again many thanks

Comment: Hi Bruce, glad the answer helps. Unfortunately I don't have any hands on experience of merging repos (only facilitating the decision). I have given the article a quick scan though and it looks fairly straight forward. I would be surprised if there is a better solution. Just one word of caution (from our experience) watch out for what happens to the git history for the repo being merged. It is, of course, nice to keep the history if you can.

Answer (score 0):

Summarizing.
First initialize the local repository if you have not already done so with `$git init`

Then add the remote repository:

```
$git remote add -f reponame https://github.com/username/reponame.git
```

combine remote repository with local

```
$git merge reponame/master --allow-unrelated-histories
```